browser instance not launching inside of virtual display with xlib selenium
hi i have an problem im new to xlib with python im trying to launch browser instance inside of vd
err lies in that vd is successfully launched  and browser instance is successfully launched but not inside of vd i guess im implemented it wrong i tried to add err  handling  but nothing seams to break
########### class for launching vd 



class DisplayWindow:
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        self.display = Xlib.display.Display()
        self.screen = self.display.screen()

        # Create window attributes manually
        self.attributes = {
            "background_pixel": self.screen.white_pixel,
            "event_mask": Xlib.X.ExposureMask | Xlib.X.ButtonPressMask,
            "border_width": 10,
            "depth": self.screen.root_depth,
            "class": Xlib.X.InputOutput,
            "visual": Xlib.X.CopyFromParent
        }

        self.window = self.create_window(width, height)
        self.set_window_title(title)

    def create_window(self, width, height):
        return self.screen.root.create_window(
            0, 0,  # x, y coordinates
            width, height,  # width, height
            **self.attributes  # Use dictionary unpacking for attributes
        )

    def set_window_title(self, title):
        self.window.set_wm_name(title)

    def launch_display(self):
        self.window.map()
        self.display.sync()
        print(f"Display ID ---->{ self.display.get_display_name()}")

    async def drag_and_drop(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):

        self.window.warp_pointer(x1, y1)
        self.display.sync()

        # Simulate left mouse button press
        fake_input(self.display, Xlib.X.ButtonPress, 1)
        self.display.sync()

        # Move the mouse pointer to the ending coordinates
        self.window.warp_pointer(x2, y2)
        self.display.sync()

        # Simulate left mouse button release
        fake_input(self.display, Xlib.X.ButtonRelease, 1)
        self.display.sync()

this is my implementation of this


    display_window.launch_display()
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

    def is_display_available(display_id):
        try:
            display = Xlib.display.Display(display_id)
            return True
        except Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError:
            return False



    
  

    if not is_display_available(':0'): 
        print("Virtual display is not available")
        exit(1)


    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.headless = True
    options.add_argument('--display=:0')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=945,1028")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"general.enable_javascript": True})

    async with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:

        pointer = driver.current_pointer
        #await driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": headers})
        
        tasks = [initialize( proxy,  pointer, driver) for _ in range(1)]
        for task in tasks:
            await task


i tryied rewriting code 3 times working with other vd lib but there not suitable for the task

Problems with code formatting

@KirillIlichev thanks
